# Testing recursive functions - C

Tags: c, function, testing, recursion

I have a small problem on my homework here

I just need to write a recursive function to test this relation

```
f(x,y)=x if y==1
```

otherwise

```
f(x,y) = x + f(x,y-1)
```

Here is my source, I can't get it to print out correctly.

Note that I have the user enter X and Y to test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int f (int x,int y);
int main (void)
{
   int x, y, z;
   printf ("\nEnter x: ");
   scanf ("%d", &x);
   printf ("\nEnter y: ");
   scanf ("%d", &y);
   x=f(x,y);
   return 0;
}

int f (int x,int y)
  {
    if (y==1)
  {
   return x;
  } 
    else
  {
    return (x + f(x,y-1));
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Your function takes three parameters but you only pass two. Your prototype (in main) is given *after* the function calls. Move the prototype up above main. And, worst of all, your "recursive" function *never calls itself*!

Comment: Where have you used recursion?

Comment: Function f  is supposed to call itself in main, but I'm also unsure on how to do this.

Comment: By-definition, a recursive function calls itself *from itself*. The initial invoke from `main` is another matter. And fair warning, the wheels are going to fall off this quickly when `y <= 0`.

Comment: A tutorial on how to create and use functions might be helpful. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm.

Comment: edited to reflect gopi's suggestion, which seems good, however it isn't returning any values. Any ideas why?

Comment: You know you don't print the result, right? You just call the function and throw the result away.

Comment: @csheroe check the below added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive function should look like:

```
  #include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = f(5,4);
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
int f (int x,int y)
{
  if (y==1)
  {
    return x;
  } 
  else
  {
    return (x + f(x,y-1));
  }
}
```

Comment: See @WhozCraig comment above about `y < 1`

Comment: @WeatherVane For a given function if it needs to be done using recursion I think this is the way to do it

Comment: Agreed, but how much stack do you have available to recurse when `y==0`?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes I see your point but if asked to use recursion then is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: `return (y < 1) ? 0 : (x + f(x,y-1));` will work for positive `int`. If the unstated and thus unknown requirement is to include negative multiplication-by-addition, it gets a little more complicated.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes sir!! The question asked was how to make a recurive function for a given function so I posted this

Comment: @csheroe it would show initiative if you mentioned to the teacher that you can't write a *practical* recursive solution unless the question was changed to `y <= 1`. Do you understand why? The same might apply for an arbitrarily large value of `y`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! Everything's all set on my end, however, although I don't like it, many of our homework assignments do seem impractical, as Weather Vane mentioned. Can you explain specifically why? Can it lead to infinite recursion?

Comment: No, if you have a big enough stack, it would work. But your stack won't be large enough to recurse the entire range of integer, because every recursion pushes more onto the stack. Get used to the fact that questions don't necessarily have a definitive solution, and the skilled teacher will ask questions that can take you beyond what is obvious.